# Python exercise TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Tags: python, typeerror

When trying to run this Python exercise:

```
s = 'azcbobobegghakl'
num = 0

for i in range (len(s)): 
    if s[i:i+3]== 'bob':
    num +=1
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(num))
```

I get this error, `TypeError: 'str' object is not callable`, on the last line. I'm a bit confused because I already turned it in at the site I'm learning from, and it was signed as correct. Can anyone here give me a hint?

Comment: That code works fine.

Comment: If I were to guess, you're using 'str' as a variable name (instead of 's' in your real code)?

Comment: Yeah your code runs fine.

Comment: Yup. I "third" that. It works fine.

Comment: Just to add to the chain of messages saying 'it works fine': tested in both python 3.6 and python 2.7 and works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code works fine. Like a user mentioned in the comments, you have probably assigned a string to a variable named `str`. Here is an example of why you would get this error:

```
str = "test"
s = 'azcbobobobegghakl'
print (s.count("bob"))
num = 0

for i in range (len(s)): 
    if s[i:i+3]== 'bob':
        num +=1
print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(num))
```

If you execute this, you get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Untitled.py", line 2197, in <module>
    print('Number of times bob occurs is: ' + str(num))
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

This is because you have defined `str` as variable and assigned it to a string `"test"`. Therefore, python thinks you are trying to call this variable on the variable `num` and since a string object is not callable, it returns an error. Therefore, you should look through any code you have not posted here and find any variables named `str` and change the name of it to something else. Never use words like `int`, `len`, or `str` for your variable names. It messes with python real bad.

P.S. If this is not the case and you do not have any variables named `str`, then I'm happy to delete my answer.

Comment: Guilty! thank you very much :p *deep shame*

Comment: @SmoothLeggedWookie that's no problems. It always happens to new users of python. Anyway, Good luck with whatever you are trying to accomplish.